# Нужно стилизовать разметку с помощью flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть следующая разметка:

```html
    <div class="container>
      <div class="block></div>
      <div class="block></div>
      <div class="big-block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
```

До определенного размера вьюпорта это обычный одноколоночный flex-контейнер:

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

После срабатывания медиа-запроса, он должен превратиться в двух-колоночный контейнер, где всю левую колонку будет занимать элемент big-block, а в правой будут остальные элементы, равномерно распределенные по высоте большого блока. Можно ли с помощью flex сделать такую сетку?

Comment: Изменять структуру html нельзя?

Comment: Структуру изменить можно, в плане порядка элементов или добавления оберток, но таким образом, чтобы до срабатывания медиа-запроса блоки внутри контейнера можно было вывести в том же порядке, в каком они указаны в коде.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container>div {
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 45%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: white;
}

.big-block {
  order: -1;
  flex: 1 0 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="big-block">big-block</div>
  <div class="block ">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а возможно получить такой же результат без фиксированной высоты? С height работает, но контент выпадает, а на свойство min-height блок уже не реагирует, и не переносит оставшиеся элементы во вторую колонку.

Comment: @FourKing, можно через js это сделать. А так, больше никак мыслей не приходит. Используйте гриды или сделайте вложенность блоков :)